# Calculating paths around complicated shape

Tags: python, numpy, path-finding

I have a several datasets for irregular 2D shapes. These datasets contain unordered points that make up the outline of shapes, but occasionally contain loops or islands of points. An example is shown below in **fig 1**. Coordinates for the shown shape are available at https://pastebin.com/0cHxPnua.

**Figure 1**

[image]

**Purpose:** I am trying to calculate a continuous line around these outlines in order to measure their perimeter, and eventually the distance between 2 points in that perimeter.

**Problem:** In the instances of complex shapes like the one shown in figure 1, the looped regions and disconnected regions can cause issues in generating a reasonable outline. I handle the islands by disregarding any connections that are much longer than the average distance between nearest point, but I haven't figured out what to do with the loops yet.

If you look below to **fig 2**, my pathfinding so far is able to handle most of the shape and successfully ignores island points, but fails after picking a bad initial path around the loop. It has to go to a new unlinked point, so it doubles back to a previously missed point near the intersection of the loop, but is then stuck as the next nearest unlinked points are beyond the distance threshold for ignoring island points.

**Figure 2** Blue start, Red end.  **Note: The last point ALWAYS connects back to the first (red)**

[image]

**Goal:** My goal here is either to chage my pathfinding method so that it can consistently handle complicated loops like these, or to find a wholly alternative method for pathfinding that is known to be applicable to this issue.

A test version of my code is available below to trial. You need to copy the shape's points from pastebin and paste them on the `points =` line

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import scipy.spatial
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection


def calculate_path_length(path):
    """
    Calculate the path length.

    Parameters:
    path (array): An array of 2D points in the path.

    Returns:
    float: The total length of the path.
    """
    return np.sum(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(path, axis=0)**2, axis=1)))


def get_shortest_path(full_path, start_point, end_point):
    """
    Get the shortest path between start and end points in a circular path.

    Parameters:
    full_path (array): An array of 2D points in the circular path.
    start_point (array): The start point.
    end_point (array): The end point.

    Returns:
    array: The shortest path.
    """
    # Get the indices of the start and end points in the full path
    start_index = np.where((full_path == start_point).all(axis=1))[0][0]
    end_index = np.where((full_path == end_point).all(axis=1))[0][0]

    # Calculate the paths
    if start_index < end_index:
        direct_path = full_path[start_index:end_index + 1]
        indirect_path = np.concatenate((full_path[end_index:], full_path[:start_index + 1]))
    else:
        direct_path = full_path[end_index:start_index + 1]
        indirect_path = np.concatenate((full_path[:end_index + 1], full_path[start_index:]))

    # Calculate the lengths of the paths
    direct_path_length = calculate_path_length(direct_path)
    indirect_path_length = calculate_path_length(indirect_path)

    # Return the shortest path
    print(direct_path_length, indirect_path_length)
    if direct_path_length < indirect_path_length:
        return direct_path
    else:
        return indirect_path


def GetPointDistance(p1, p2):
    return np.sqrt( ((p2[0] - p1[0])**2) + ((p2[1] - p1[1])**2) )


def AverageDistanceWithBuffer(points, buffer_size=20):
    """
    Calculate the average distance of a group of points and add buffer_size standard deviations to 
    add a large ceiling for distance variances. This should still be able to exclude extremely 
    large deviations that occur when outliers are present.

    Parameters:
    points (list): 2D list of 2xN points.
    buffer_size (int): Padding multiplier to use for outlier rejection.

    Returns:
    float: The average distance with buffer.
    """
    distances = []
    for i, point in enumerate(points):
        if i != len(points) - 1:
            distances.append(GetPointDistance(point, points[i+1]))
    return np.mean(distances) + buffer_size * np.std(distances)
    

def random_downsample(arr, percentage):
    """
    Randomly downsample an array by the given percentage.

    Parameters:
    arr (array): The input array.
    percentage (float): The percentage of data to retain.

    Returns:
    array: The downsampled array.
    """
    if percentage <= 0 or percentage > 100:
        raise ValueError("Percentage should be between 0 and 100 (inclusive).")

    sample_size = int(len(arr) * percentage / 100)
    random_indices = np.random.choice(len(arr), sample_size, replace=False)
    sampled_arr = arr[random_indices]

    return sampled_arr



def shortest_path(points, start_point, end_point):
    """
    Find the shortest path between start and end points.

    Parameters:
    points (array): An array of 2D points.
    start_point (array): The start point.
    end_point (array): The end point.

    Returns:
    array: The full path.
    array: The shortest path between the start and end points.
    """
    points = points.tolist()
    start_point = start_point.tolist()
    end_point = end_point.tolist()
    points = points + [start_point, end_point]
    current_point = start_point
    full_path = [current_point]
    points.remove(current_point)

    use_cutoff = False
    while points:
        if len(full_path) == 1000:
            buffered_avg_dist = AverageDistanceWithBuffer(full_path)
            use_cutoff = True

        if len(points) == 1 and points[0] == end_point:
            full_path.append(end_point)
            points.remove(end_point)
        else:
            closest_point = min(points, key=lambda x: np.linalg.norm(np.array(current_point) - np.array(x)))
            closest_point_dist = GetPointDistance(current_point, closest_point)
            if use_cutoff:
                if closest_point_dist < buffered_avg_dist:
                    full_path.append(closest_point)
                    current_point = closest_point
            else:
                full_path.append(closest_point)
                current_point = closest_point
            points.remove(closest_point)
        

    # To form a closed loop for the full perimeter path
    full_path.append(start_point)

    # Shortest path from start to end
    shortest_path = get_shortest_path(np.array(full_path), start_point, end_point)

    plt.scatter(shortest_path[:, 0], shortest_path[:, 1], c=range(len(shortest_path)), cmap='inferno')
    plt.close()

    # Convert lists into numpy arrays
    full_path = np.array(full_path)
    shortest_path = np.array(shortest_path)

    return full_path, shortest_path


points = # Copy points from https://pastebin.com/0cHxPnua
points = np.array(points)

# Returns a full path and the shortest path between the start and end points
full, shortest = shortest_path(points, points[48], points[int(len(points)/2)])  # Arbitrary Start and End points

# Plot the outline
plt.scatter(points[0, 0], points[0, 1], s=200, facecolor='red', zorder=1000)  # Plot start point
plt.scatter(points[int(len(points)/2), 0], points[int(len(points)/2), 1], s=200, facecolor='green', zorder=1000)  # Plot end point
plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1])  # Plot all points
plt.plot(full[:, 0], full[:, 1], color='k')  # Plot path line
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: An alternative method is a flood fill from the outside of the shape using a large spot size. [The result looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km6AR.png). Once the fill is completed, the perimeter is the inside edge of the fill area.

Comment: @user3386109 This is a very interesting idea I hadn't considered! 
Here is where I am unsure of the application though. Would I run flood fill, take the points that touch my outline and then calculate a new path using those points? So that I no longer have to include pockets? I would appreciate if you shared this code with me too, but only if you are willing!

Answer (score 1):

You can repair loops after obtaining closed path by finding intersected segments and repairing it by unraveling. Below my code and final result for your test points.

```
def get_raw_path(start_index, dist_matrix, dist, dist_threshold, points):
    # start index - where to start our path
    # dist matrix - sorted indexes of distance matrix
    # dist - distance matrix
    # threshold - if distance > threshold don't use this lines
    walked_points = [start_index]
    path = [start_index]
    segments = []
    
    for x in range(dist_matrix.shape[0]):
        # Get distances for last point in path
        candidates = dist_matrix[path[-1]]
        for point in candidates:
            # Get the nearest point if ...
            if  point not in walked_points and dist[path[-1],point] < dist_threshold:
                walked_points.append(point)
                path.append(point)            
                segments.append([path[-2], path[-1]])
                break
                
        # Check for intersection and mend if intersection exists
        while True:
            is_intersect, si = find_segment_for_intersection(segments, points)
            if is_intersect:
                #print ("Start unraveling ...")
                old_chain = segments[si:]
                #print("Old chain: -->", segments[si:])
                segments[si][1], segments[-1][0] = segments[-1][0], segments[si][1]
                segments[si+1:-1] = [x[::-1] for x in segments[si+1:-1][::-1]]
                #print("New chain: -->", segments[si:])
                path = [start_index]
                for s in segments:
                    path.append(s[-1])
            else:
                break
            
            
    path.append(start_index)
    
    return path

# This code is not mine
def ccw(A,B,C):
    return (C[1]-A[1])*(B[0]-A[0]) > (B[1]-A[1])*(C[0]-A[0])

def intersect(A,B,C,D):
        return ccw(A,C,D) != ccw(B,C,D) and ccw(A,B,C) != ccw(A,B,D)

    
def find_segment_for_intersection(segments, points):
    last_segment = segments[-1]
    C, D = points[last_segment[0]], points[last_segment[1]]
    for si, segment in enumerate(segments):
        if not (set(segment) & set(last_segment)):
            A, B = points[segment[0]], points[segment[1]]
            if intersect(A, B, C, D):
                return (True, si)
    return (False, 0)

# Load Points
points = np.load("points", allow_pickle=True)
print("Loading points ...")
print("points.shape -->", points.shape)

# Get unique points
unique_points = np.unique(points, axis=0)
print("Get {} unique points".format(unique_points.shape[0]))

print("Calculating distance matrix ...")
x, y = unique_points[:,0][:,None], unique_points[:,1][:,None]
dist = np.sqrt(np.square(x - x.T) + np.square(y - y.T))
print("Sorting distances ...")
dist_sort = np.argsort(dist)

print("Getting path approximation ...")
path = get_raw_path(0, dist_sort, dist, 10, unique_points)
print("Path length -->", len(path))
print("{} points are isolated".format(len(unique_points) - len(path)))
path_coords = unique_points[path]
print(path)
# Find all intersection ...

# Plot the outline
plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
#plt.scatter(upoints[0, 0], upoints[0, 1], s=200, facecolor='red', zorder=1000)  # Plot start point
#plt.scatter(upoints[int(len(upoints)/2), 0], upoints[int(len(upoints)/2), 1], s=200, facecolor='green', zorder=1000)  # Plot end point
plt.scatter(unique_points[:, 0], unique_points[:, 1], s=0.5)  # Plot all points
plt.plot(path_coords[:, 0], path_coords[:, 1], color='k', linewidth=0.3)  # Plot path line
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Result image:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer! I'm trying to understand how everything is functioning right now so I can attempt to add it into my code, but in the meantime I had a question about the segment cross solution. While it does clean most of the perimeter up, I'm unsure why it misses some sections, especially in the top right, as you are continually trying to solve crosses until it no longer detects them.

Comment: You're right, sorry! There is still 2 loops which were generated when code trying eradicating bigger loops. We can do one more intersection check at the end of the get_raw_path function until full cleaning will be achieved. I did check at the time of path construction because it requires less computational steps. When number of loops decreased and simlified we can do intersection check on full path one more time.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but based on your code I thought that each segment would be continually fixed until all loops were removed because of the way `find_segment_for_intersection()` and the while loop interact.